# Method of deploying a VB6 app to a Windows server 2012 RDS server

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtualization, windows-server-2012, application

My environment currently has a Windows 2003 server running terminal services. That server has the visual studio 6 IDE installed. It also is responsible for running a very old ( and poorly built ) VB6 application. I'm currently testing methods for deploying a Windows server 2012 running the RDS role to our employees. One of the major hurdles has been making that legacy VB6 application available to the 2012 RDS server. Up to this point I've only found success in having an RDS client connected to the 2012 server then run a RDP session to the 2003 server to execute the legacy app. I'm trying to make the process of running that legacy app more seamless to the users. Is there a method where I could have a more seamless execution of that legacy app for the RDS clients of the 2012 server? I've been looking at Microsoft's App-V product but am still unsure if this will accomplish what I'm looking for.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the install/application on the 2012 server?

Comment: There is no install that I know of. The app was simply built in the IDE and then run locally. Because the development server is a Terminal Services host it was never "installed". The IDE will not install on the 2012 server however and when i try to access the app remotely there are a host of OCXs that fail and after that, many recordsets return empty values. It seemed like a bad idea to chase installation and to try and move to virtualization until the app is re-written.

Comment: Many VB6 apps should work on 2012.  It is possible that you may need to select a compatibility mode.

Answer (score 3):

> App-V virtualizes the application.  Use App-V when the application you want to use runs on your host OS, but doesn’t interact well with other applications on your host OS.

...

> MED-V uses a virtual machine to host your application.  Use MED-V when the application you want to deploy does not run on your host OS.

(Source: http://blogs.technet.com/b/uspartner_ts2team/archive/2010/04/20/what-s-the-difference-between-app-v-and-med-v.aspx)

Whether VB6 is supported or not on Server 2012 and Server 2012 R2 is a rabbit hole. Regardless of it is or not, I would personally not want it installed on my server because it is ancient. Therefore, I would prefer a Med-V solution as opposed to installing VB6 directly on my shiny new server.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I need to buy time while the app is re-written. Med-V sounds like it does exactly what I'm looking for. I'm going to go read up on it.

Comment: Med-V does look like its target is my exact situation. Thanks for the info Ryan.

Comment: I've found an issue. Because our business runs 100% on thin clients it looks as if using MED-V on Server 2012 may not be supported or possible.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548504.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well,,,I'm ancient. I still program in VB6 although moving across to VS2010 yet still using the Jet Engine!!!

You need to ensure the appropriate DLLs and OCXs are in and registered in the Windows System directory. Done using an install set. They can be copied and manually registered (regsvr32)

My stuff works on the latest 64bit Servers as VB Applications (GUI) and also VB6 code linked with Apache and PHP...100% robust, never a problem. Never.

I am slowly migrating to VS2010 as seemless as possible. VS2010 screens are crispier than VB6 else no difference. Still using DAO. ADO is mega slow. SQL Server...maybe, but, don't forget, it's all ones and noughts and I was programming when there was no such thing as a "database".

If you want an "install set" then get contact me at andy.hilbig@clubsys.co.uk